# celery can not conect to redis in docker

Tags: django, docker, redis, celery

i set all confing and see all question in stackoverflow but celery can not conect to redis and i get this error when i run docker-compose up in pycharm termal.

```
consumer: Cannot connect to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused..
```

this is my docker-compose i try to connect all servis to main network.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:7.2-alpine3.18
    networks:
      - main

  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:16
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=shop
      - POSTGRES_USER=comiser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Hosein67
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - shop-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./data/web:/vol/web
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - main

  celery:
    container_name: celery
    command: celery -A shop worker -l INFO
    depends_on:
      - db
      - app
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
    build:
      context: .
    networks:
      - main


networks:
  main:

volumes:
  shop-data:
```

this is my celery.py. i try best practic to confing celery

```
from celery import Celery
from datetime import timedelta
import os


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'shop.envs.development')

app = Celery('shop', broker='redis://redis:6379/0')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

app.conf.result_backend = 'rpc://'
app.conf.task_serializer = 'json'
app.conf.result_serializer = 'pickle'
app.conf.accept_content = ['json', 'pickle']
app.conf.result_expires = timedelta(days=1)
app.conf.task_always_eager = False
app.conf.worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
```

i add this tow line to my setting , i edit it to localhost and everything but it doest not work.

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
```

and this is my init in the main project

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .celery import app as celery_app


__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Comment: Use `redis` as hostname.